# Setting inital View on a View Based Aplication

Tags: xcode

I No how to go from One window to Another using An IBAction and and Button but I was wandering if their is a way to do the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" BOOL Currently (unchanged since created) it looks like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

any help on this matter would be greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet for 2 hours it became apparent that I was the only one to have asked such a question. but after 1 and a half hours of solid failure I have made a solution. there are 3 things you must do first you must go into the appDelegate.h and change the following

```
@class originalpageVeiwController;

@interface snakeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    originalpageVeiwController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet originalpageVeiwController *viewController;

@end
```

change the @class originalpageVeiwController to secoundpageViewController and do the same for the rest of that file (2 more occurences in basic file (@interface and @ property)).

Then open MainWindow.xib and click on the originalpageVeiwController icon and go onto attributes inspector(⌘1) and change the NibName under ViewController to secoundpageViewController and then go onto the identity inspector (⌘4) and change the class under class identity to secoundpageViewController and then save changes to the MainWindow and build and run.